# Android Studio Issue: Loads incorrect content in many files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

When I create a new project, many files are being generated incomplete 
like colors.xml, mipmap files and many more.

Already tried the following:-

- Invalidate cache and restart.
- Deleted temp files from my PC.
- Uninstalled Android Studio and reinstalled it but after some time the
  same problem occurred again.

I am attaching Images to some files which are incomplete

Please give some suggestions or anyone else who had the same problem can help me out.

[image: Incomplete File Image]

[image: Incomplete File Image 2]

Comment: there's a lot wrong with your Android Studio installation. I recommend cleaning all folders like the /Android folder on your home drive and then reinstall Android Studio

Comment: As I have clearly mentioned in my post, I already reinstalled android studio but the problem is still there. And I can successfully open and run old projects, so there is no problem with my installation.

Comment: Close the project which is in the file option. And open the project again from the exact location by clicking on the open existing android studio project and see it will work @Dharmik

Comment: @MohamedNiyaz it does not work

Comment: you checked it  ? @DharmikThakkar. If that is the case shall u tell what is the build error !

Comment: I posted the answer below...It worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps:-

1. Close the Android Studio.
2. Go to:
   C:\users\your_user_name\.AndroidStudio3.4\system\caches
3. Delete the caches folder.
4. Go to:
   C:\Users\your_user_name\.gradle\caches
5. Delete this caches folder also.
6. Now you can start your Android Studio and start working.

Your Problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. some of the layout xml files are displayed with odd characters in android studio. The studio does not show them in xml format. These files are fine outside the studio and open well with notepad or any browser.

I deleted the caches as stated above and everything is fine. Android studio is showing up the files correctly.

Comment: If you found the above answer helpful do not write a new answer below it stating it is helpful. Just upvote the question and answer that u found helpful.